# Synchronize and Update database android application from website

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, synchronization

I have problems.
I create an application which is on starting it will synchronize the database in external storage with database on website if any data changed it will appear dialog to ask "Do u want update". 
I put my database on website http://example.com/folder/mydb.db 
and for android I put it on external at data/data/database/mydb
How to check any database changed?

Comment: Need more information about the server side of it.  Bottom line: you'll have to have some way for the server to give you either a timestamp of its last update or a changeset or something.

Comment: I put my database on website http://websitename/folder/mydb.db and for android I put it on external at data/data/database

Comment: This is a bad idea, for many reasons.  First, with respect to the original question, you'd have to download the whole database and open it to check for modifications.  You need a middle layer (web service or something) between your app and the database if you have any regard for things like security, performance, scalability, or maintainability.

Comment: can you give me explanation about middle layer(web service or something). For sure, my application just want to compare between database at external storage n database on website if content of database is same or not it will give dialog

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the file you upload, adding the version number so you can just compare the file name to check for modification.

If different, download and override your existing DB using the tutorial here: 
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/